# Fast range/interval lookup for data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, indexing

I have a dataset where I need to request key, value data (e.g. time series data) from any arbitrary range. How do I do this so that it runs as quickly as possible?

I am thinking of something similar to how Python pandas does range slicing.

**Example:**

Data are key, value Pairs: (0, value), (10, value), (20, value), (30, value), (41, value), (51, value), (60, value)...

Query: Give me data points from time ranges 10 to 40.

One possibility is building a tree of intervals, traversing the tree to find the matching array positions, then using Arrays.copyOfRange.

Comment: @J Wang you want write yourself or can use tools ?

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head you could use a [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (there are two implementations in the JDK), it has a [subMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-) method that is slice like.

Alternatively an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Key, Value pairs (sorted by Key). Find the end of the ranges using [Collection.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) and then [sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) to get your slice.

Comment: ...an _ordered_ ArrayList, or an array, if `Data` doesn't change.

Comment: Lists are always ordered, but i'll update my answer to say sorted by time. I didn't specify using an array because it doesn't have a slice method, and given that an arraylist is backed by an array I don't see that there is much difference.